# Middleware to exclude file type from authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, middleware

I have this middleware, which checks to see if the user is authenticated against all requests that come in.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
        && context.Request.Path != "/Home/Index"
        && context.Request.Path != "/Home/Login")
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

However, there is a file type (PBF) that doesn't need to be secure. The request would be something like:

> context.Request.Path = site/folder/68-09.pbf

Essentially these files are binary files that are used to render objects onto an open street map when a user drags their mouse into a Geolocation, so these files could be rendered 100 times a second! Therefore I would like to avoid checking them in the middleware to may be speed the site up.

I have tried this:

```
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".pbf"), appBuilder =>
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            && context.Request.Path != "/Home/Index"
            && context.Request.Path != "/Home/Login")
        {
            await context.ChallengeAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    });
});
```

But it doesn't avoid the PBF files, is this possible, and if so, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the nested `app.Use()` to `appBuilder.Use()`:

```
asp.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".pbf"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            && context.Request.Path != "/Home/Index"
            && context.Request.Path != "/Home/Login")
        {
            await context.ChallengeAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    });
});
```